# how many nib file I need to support iPhone 3G, iPhone 5 and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nib, iphone-5, screen-size

If I want to support and design with old iOS and iPhone, how many nib I may need? Will it be 3 nib, one for older iPhones, one for iPhone 5 and one for iPad? Surely I do not want the black border below for iPhone 5. I want to use the whole screen for iPhone 5.

Or is there any good work around without using 3 nibs?

What are the pros and cons to avoid 3 nibs and do everything in code? any good tips?

Comment: maybe only 2 if you target for iOS 6 and use auto layouts

Comment: I want to support ols iOSes. So auto layout is not an option for me, not it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only 2 nib. One for iPhone and one for iPad. older iPhones and iPhone 5 it's can be on the same nib by using auto layout methods

[Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202)

Comment: In that case, in iPhone 5, there will be a black border below, not it?

Comment: No. With Auto layout the size has increased automatically. Watch the Video ;)

Comment: But Auto layout is for iOS 6 only, he wants to support older iOS versions

Comment: Oops, sorry. Yes if he wants to support any iOS he would need 3 nibs

Comment: @thedjnivek Not really. It's possible to use autoresizing masks instead of autolayout in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible to have one nib and make it fit the whole screen, regardless of iPhone/iPad versions using the old struts and springs layout. This will give you some control of how the different elements scales on the different devices, but it is quite limited.

In the end it depends on what you want to display:

1. If the content can be stretched and look good on all devices, one nib should be ok.
2. If you need to make some bigger adjustments to take advantage of devices with bigger screens and higher resolutions, you need seperate nibs for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two nib files.

You can programmaticly check for your screensize (if it's an iPhone 5) with:

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationframe].size.height == 568){
   //configure your stuff for iPhone 5
}
```

Within this if-statement you can do your view configuration.

If you want to push it even further you can also check for the screensize of the iPad and only use 1 nib file. But for easier use I suggest you use the stuff mentioned above.